# NCrunch always disabled whenever I open a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ncrunch

I'm currently using NCrunch 1.48.0.5 in Visual Studio 2010.

Every time I open a solution I find that NCrunch is disabled. How can I open a solution and have NCrunch enabled by default?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." - To whoever downvoted this question, this does involve a tool (NCrunch) primarily used for programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to force NCrunch to auto-enable on start-up. You can do this by setting "AutoEnableOnStartup" to true e.g.

```
<SolutionConfiguration>
    <AutoEnableOnStartup>true</AutoEnableOnStartup>
    ...
</SolutionConfiguration>
```

within the NCRUNCHSOLUTION file, which is found in the same directory as the solution file e.g.

```
YourSoultion.ncrunchsolution
```

More information can be found in the documentation [here](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/v1/reference_solution-configuration_overview)

Comment: Glad you were able to find your solution. Is this a setting you can set in the global configuration file as well? Just curious but it seems setting per solution is better for some.

Comment: Fyi... You can use project configuration file for even more granular control - http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_project-configuration_overview

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SoftwareCarpenter. I felt bad re-assigning the answer, but your answer is still very useful and you've got upvotes too. Yes, you can configure global, solution and project properties. I'm glad I found this setting as it was driving me mad having to re-configure NCrunch every time the solution was loaded!

Comment: The answer is more specific, so no big deal. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**By default, NCrunch will always start as disabled for a solution before it is explicitly turned on from the top menu.**

You can toggle Ncrunch on and off from the by selecting Enable from the NCrunch Visual Studio menu.

[There is also a global configuration file that has many config settings that you can use.](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/reference_global-configuration_overview)

[ncrunch documentation](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/guides_quick-start-guide)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SoftwareCarpenter. Yes I know that I can toggle it on/off from within the VS menu, it's just that I'd like it to be enabled by default. Can't find an appropriate setting in the NCrunch documentation.

Comment: Have you tried running the configuration wizard or selecting NCrunch->Configuration? You might want to try reinstalling.

Comment: Ok, so it always starts disabled by default. Whilst this isn't the behaviour I want (once I've enabled it for a solution I want it to stay enabled!) I'll mark this as the answer (plus the global config file could come in useful!)

Comment: I did find a way to force Visual Studio to run the tests on start-up. See my answer.